# is there a way to animate a lot of bones moving the same way one after another?

Tags: animation

I have about 140 bones which I want to move down and each starting at the same point but I want each to start moving a few frames after the previos one the same way and stop them all at once.

Comment: didn't try this one but see if it helps : [arewo](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/downloads/537-arewo-gui-a-detailed-description.html)

Comment: I need them to stop all at once, which means, that each has a little bit different trajectory (the ones, which start latter will have shorter trajectory). I think this would enable me to copy the movement with offset.

Comment: I think you'll need a script for that

Comment: I was wandering maybe if I gave each bone copy location constraint with offset and somehow set it so that it would start moving when the space between the two bones is big enough.